# Roaming User (Networked) of winform app claims apps hangs due to onedrive syncing

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, network-programming, synchronization

A roaming user (networked, with admin privileges, Win 10) stated that (A) onedrive syncing over the network is slowing down the winform app, and (B) requested to be able to set a default folder for data access.

Question: firstly, shouldn't the user be asked to work with their IT to find out what folder won't result in any data access issues or onedrive sync issues?  For a temp workaround, is there anything wrong with also telling the user to use the roaming folders among the following:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

and then modify the code to allow users to set a default data folder with a try-catch obviously?

My gut feeling is that the user is getting hung up in ...\OneDrive\MyDocuments which I think is what would be returned by .ApplicationData.  Also, just because a user wants to set a default data directory doesn't mean that his enterprise will allow him to go anywhere he wants on a disk of workstation at the office that he remotes into(?)

Comment: In regards to One Drive https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-onedrive-sync-app-upload-or-download-rate-71cc69da-2371-4981-8cc8-b4558bdda56e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US  I don't know what they mean by set a data access folder. Usually data returned from a server is in memory unless you explicitly save is to disk. In which care give him a Save dialog box and let him put it where ever he wants (and then hunt for it later)

Comment: thanks for the tip!